# How to apply logical comparisons to categorical variables in case when conditions in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data-frame like below.  It has categorical column (band) which has hierarchy going from 0,G1,G2,G3  to G4 where G4 being the highest.

I want to rewrite the below SQL logic in pandas

```
CASE
         WHEN Band = '00' THEN access.Y
         WHEN Band = 'G1' THEN acess.X +200
         WHEN Band >= 'G2' THEN acess.X +access.Y

       END  As Result
       From access
```

**Dataframe**

```
Band    X   Y     Result
00     200  2100    2100
G1     300  2300    500
G2     200  5000    5200
G3     150  6000    6150
00     250  2500    2500
G1     400  6000    600
G2     300  6000    6300
G4     500  4500    5000
```

How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) here (*for general cases to handle categorical sorting and comparisons*) to be able to use comparative operators such as `>=` in categorical series and then use `np.select` for using `if,elif,else` conditions.

```
df['Band'] = pd.Categorical(df['Band'],categories=['00','G1','G2','G3','G4'],ordered=True)

df['result']=np.select([df['Band']=='00',df['Band']=='G1',df['Band']>='G1']
                       ,[df['Y'],df['X']+200,df['X'].add(df['Y'])])
print(df)
```

---

```
  Band    X     Y  Result  result
0   00  200  2100    2100    2100
1   G1  300  2300    2600     500
2   G2  200  5000    5200    5200
3   G3  150  6000    6150    6150
4   00  250  2500    2500    2500
5   G1  400  6000    6400     600
6   G2  300  6000    6300    6300
7   G4  500  4500    5000    5000
```

Details : 
If we print the series now, we would be able to see the hirearchy:

```
print(df['Band'])

0    00
1    G1
2    G2
3    G3
4    00
5    G1
6    G2
7    G4
Name: Band, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [00 < G1 < G2 < G3 < G4]
```

Comment: if  I want to add `Else Null` to above logic. What should be done

Comment: @pankaj you can pass your desired variavle at the end, by default it is `np.nan`, for string  `Null` use  `np.select([df['Band']=='00',df['Band']=='G1',df['Band']>='G1']
                       ,[df['Y'],df['X']+200,df['X'].add(df['Y'])],'Null')` but note that string `Null` will change the dtype of the series so not advisable

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['res'] = (np.select([df['Band']=='00', df['Band'] == 'G1'],
                       [df['Y'], df['X'] + 200],
                        df['X'] + df['Y']))
print (df)
  Band    X     Y  Result   res
0   00  200  2100    2100  2100
1   G1  300  2300    2600   500
2   G2  200  5000    5200  5200
3   G3  150  6000    6150  6150
4   00  250  2500    2500  2500
5   G1  400  6000    6400   600
6   G2  300  6000    6300  6300
7   G4  500  4500    5000  5000
```

If there are `G` with number convert to categorical is not necessary:

```
df['res'] = (np.select([df['Band']=='00', df['Band'] == 'G1', df['Band']>='G1'],
                       [df['Y'], df['X'] + 200, df['X'] + df['Y']]))
print (df)
  Band    X     Y  Result   res
0   00  200  2100    2100  2100
1   G1  300  2300    2600   500
2   G2  200  5000    5200  5200
3   G3  150  6000    6150  6150
4   00  250  2500    2500  2500
5   G1  400  6000    6400   600
6   G2  300  6000    6300  6300
7   G4  500  4500    5000  5000
```

Comment: @jezeral,I had small change in my logic, I just updated it. Can you have look. I have 3 conditions